# Login System causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, web

I am working on a login system for a website and produced a system that checks the user's credentials against my database and redirects the user based on if the information is correct or not. I have now implemented a system to prevent the user from accessing the page if they are not currently logged in however once directed to this page chrome produces the following error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I will list below all the code that I feel is relevant but feel free to ask for anything else you feel is needed.

The file that checks credentials against the database:

```
<?php
// check login logic here
require('../includes/sessions.inc.php');
require('../includes/conn.inc.php');

$userLogin = filter_var($_POST['userLogin'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if($userLogin) {
    //email good
    //check if in database next
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userLogin = :userLogin";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userLogin', $userLogin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $numUsers = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($numUsers == 0){
        // email not in database error
        $_SESSION['loginError'] = 1;
        $referer = "loginFail.php";
        }else{
            // need to check password next
            $row =$stmt->fetchObject();
            $dbPasswordHash = $row->userPassword;
            if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $dbPasswordHash)) {
                unset($_SESSION['loginError']);
                $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
                $referer = "cms/cms.php";
            }else{
                // database does not match error
                $_SESSION['loginError'] = 1;
                $referer = "loginFail.php";
            }   
        }        
}else{
    //Not valid email error
    $_SESSION['loginError'] = 1;
    $referer = "loginFail.php";
}
header("Location: ../".$referer);
?>
```

The 'authorize' file to check that a user is logged in before displaying the page:

```
<?php
// check if session login and redirect if not
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header('Location: ../cms/cms.php');
    exit;
}
else
{
    header('Location: ../loginFail.php');
    exit; 
}
?>
```

To check that the user is logged in before showing the cms page I use the following:

```
require('../includes/authorize.inc.php');
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Following an answer I have updated the authorize file to the following:

```
<?php
// check if session login and redirect if not
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header('Location: ../loginFail.php');
    exit; 
}
?>
```

With this change, even a correct username & password will redirect me to loginFail.php when it should be redirecting me to the cms. I believe there is an issue when checking if the user is logged in using the authorize file as the initial login works but once on the cms page it redirects back to the login.

Comment: Your code redirects me to the cms if i am not logged in..huh?

Comment: This is what happens if you not logged in the code redirects you to cms.php and I'm sure when you are on cms.php you are redirected back to login then login redirects you also.. so its a redirect loop,

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){`  Change this condition

Comment: plz output your `$_SESSION['login']` and exit to checkt if it is set

Answer (score 0):

If you include your script on each page you got always a redirected ... I think it's working better if you only redirect if he is not logged in.

```
<?php
// include on all protectet sites
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header('Location: ../loginFail.php');
    exit;
}
//stay in loginarea
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this, however, it has caused another issue which I have now outlined in the original post.

Comment: you are sure the session exists before you lock for the login?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're stuck in a redirect loop going to
header('Location: ../loginFail.php'); 
then for some reason you automaticaly trying to log in, failing, and redirecting again back to loginFail.php

check your
$userLogin = filter_var($_POST['userLogin'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
and see why $userLogin has post values or perhaps a null object passes 
if($userLogin) {
in your code.